# How to set a default starting page in nativescript Angular

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I built a nativescript project with `tns create appname --template ng` ,
it uses `page-router-outlet`,the nativescript docs say that the newest component is what starts up and I have page i want to start up first, is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try changing default route to your desire component in `app.routing.ts`

for example:

try changing below code

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", redirectTo: "/items", pathMatch: "full" },
    { path: "items", component: ItemsComponent },
    { path: "item/:id", component: ItemDetailComponent },
];
```

To

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", redirectTo: "/yourcomponent", pathMatch: "full" },
    { path: "items", component: ItemsComponent },
    { path: "item/:id", component: ItemDetailComponent },
    { path: "yourcomponent", component: YourComponent },

];
```